# How to bring forward an element on the windows form so it appears ontop of another element

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Basically (excuse the really bad pun) i want to bring forward a menu bar (not docked) so it is on top of a picutebox (docked on top of form) however i cant seem to achieve this.e.g. [image: Before i attempt to put it on the top] and as you can see i cant get the menu to appear on top.[image: After the attempt]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In code you can use the `.BringToFront` method to change the Z order of controls. In the designer you can use the `Format` menu. Select the control and use `Format->Order` (rough translation from german) to change the Z-order.

There should also be icons in your toolbar:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Im new to VB and i couldn't figure out how for the life of me.

Comment: This is why intellisense is a life saver when you're just starting out and don't know what methods or events exist to help you.  You can always look at what public methods a particular object or element has available and just try out any whose name sounds likely to be helpful.  Best of luck to you.